# Steam Trade Offer как послать запрос и получить информацию, принял ли его человек

Tags: php, python, steam-web-api, steam

День добрый господа. Делаю трейд бота для Steam. Задача такая - послать запрос человеку на обмен и удостовериться, что он его принял. Если можно пример на PHP/Python сделать, буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно будет отслеживать ваши запросы и иногда просматривать их статус. Библиотека на PHP для Steam можно найти [тут](https://github.com/halipso/php-steam-tradeoffers). Как пример - сохраняете все запросы в файл, и затем каждые X минут делаете запрос статуса по этим запросам, обновляя их и реагируя на принятие предложения.